# trying to keep something dry

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dry

I have written some javascript that creates an array of objects and then performs some actions on said array. At the moment, every time I want to use it, I need to repopulate the array, and then run two other functions. Here is my usage:

```
queue_obj.build_queue_object($('.section_pane.visible .queue_list .post_row:not(.hidden)'))
.initialise_queue_view()
.add_event_listeners();
```

I am having to write this code all over my codebase which is not ideal. Is it possible to change it up so I can use it from one place.

i.e initialise the data once. If it changes, re-initialise it or update it.

Below is the full code:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

var queue_obj = {
    'items' : [],
    build_queue_object : function(posts) {
        $(window).off('scroll resize');
        this.items = [];
        var that = this;
        $(posts).each(function(i, el){
            that.items[i] = {
                element : $(this),
                child_element : $(this).find('.post_row_inner')
            }
        });

        return this;
    },

    initialise_queue_view : function() {
        this.items.forEach(function(obj, i){
            if(obj.element.isInViewport())
            {
                obj.child_element.removeClass('pagination_hidden');
            }
            else
            {
                obj.child_element.addClass('pagination_hidden');
            }
        });

        return this;
    },

    add_event_listeners : function() {
        var that = this;
        $(window).on('scroll resize', function(){
            that.initialise_queue_view();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You could wrap that function in another function in a new scope, then call that very short function wherever you need it to appear.

Comment: What exactly does this reinitialization change to the array? Do you mean updating the child nodes? And if so, why is this needed, compared to finding the child nodes when you actually use them? I also don't really understand the scroll functionality. Why not just constrain the display to x items per page with CSS and let normal scrolling do the rest? Pagination does not offer many benefits if you render the entire array anyways and then hide everything not in view.

Comment: @shilly The array is basically 100s-1000s of dom elements, these elements can either exist or not exists dependant on what the user is filtering, hence why every filter I need to reinitialise it. Otherwise I could be looping over stuff that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: You are paginating an array of up to 1k elements correct? Have you tried your current approach with that many elements? I get way better results with just filtering the source data and rerendering an entire chunk (page of x elements according to viewport size ) than by keeping a manual tally of all the DOM elements, especially on mobile. Imho DOM should reflect state, not be state.

Comment: @shilly it has to be this way for now until we factor the server side. Basically I have 1000(ish) dom elements but only display/draw what is currently in the viewport meanung that I only need to paint maybe 10 at page load. However these dom elements can change based on filter so hence the need to update the array.

Comment: I don't understand anymore. Sorry for wasting your time.